# Whats wrong with my iteration list of lists from csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm tyring to create a list of lists.  So I want to put every line of text in a separate list within the climatelist.

This is my code:

```
import re
with open('klimaat].txt', 'r') as file:
    reading = re.split('\n', file.read())
    climate = [reading[i:i+4] for i in range(18, len(reading) - 1,10)]

print(climate)
```

https://pastebin.com/jXxnPsQA

I dont know why it takes more than 4 strings into my list. If i print readings[someindex] I get exactly that line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
content = []
with open(fname) as f:
    content.append([f.readline()])
```

Also as a one liner:

```
content = [[line] for line in open('fname')]
```

Note that `'\n'` can be removed with `str.rstrip('\n')`.
You can further post process your lines in order to drop all empty lines (e.g. lines that contain only `'\n'`) or insert it as an if statement in the list comprehension:

```
content = [[line] for line in open('fname') if line != '\n']
```

Comment: Hi Sky 
Thanks for your help!
I just have to figure out how to get this stripfunction through all my lists, but I got further this way.